# Variable property jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties

I need to style a div's unknown property.

```
var property = 'width';
$('#div').css({[property]: '100px'});
```

I figured the brackets would have worked but no such luck. Anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: That syntax belongs to upcoming ES6! Use `var o = {}; o[property] = 'value'` instead.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrd81ks/)***

You could just create a new function object.

```
var property = 'width';
$('#div').css(new function(){this[property] = '100px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you are trying to use belongs to the upcoming ECMAScript6. The bracket notation is used for computing the property name and the feature is called "Computed property name".

```
var identifier = 'Identifier';
{ ['an' + identifer]: 'value' } // { anIdentifier: 'value' }
{ [identifier.toUpperCase()]: 'value' } // { IDENTIFIER: 'value' }
```

Currently only Firefox 34+ support this feature. The current widespread ES5 doesn't support it. You could code:

```
var property = 'width';
var styles = {};
styles[property] = '100px';

$('#div').css(styles);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#div').css(property, value);
```

In the above example `property` should be a String.

Comment: Won't you always know what properties you want to affect anyways?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why this option isn't even working for me.

Comment: You need to replace `value` with `100px` or something.